# What does .tar-1 in a filename obtained by gunzip a tar.gz mean?

Tags: tar

I downloaded a zipped tar-file `filename.tar.gz` and  after converting it with the `gunzip` command it is now named `filename.tar-1`. What does the `-1` mean?

Comment: Do you have `gunzip` aliased to `gunzip -N`?

Comment: thanks, that solved it. But I'm still curious. Is tar-1 something like an error-code? I couldn't find it anywhere

Answer (score 6):

You would see this behavior if your `gunzip` is aliased to `gunzip -N` and the original file name was `filename-1`. To illustrate:

```
$ ls
filename-1
$ gzip filename-1

$ mv filename-1.gz filename.gz

$ gunzip -Nv filename.gz
filename.gz:     -0.5% -- replaced with filename-1
```

From `man gunzip`:

```
   -N --name
          When  compressing,  always  save the original file name and time
          stamp; this is the  default.  When  decompressing,  restore  the
          original  file  name  and  time stamp if present. This option is
          useful on systems which have a limit on file name length or when
          the time stamp has been lost after a file transfer.
```